# Creating complex JSON payload from Java Pojo Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I want to create below JSON payload

```
{
 "maxResults":3,
 "counter":0,
 "customerParameters":{
    "filters":[
        {
            "name":"customerId",
            "operator":"=",
            "value":["hello"]
        }
        ]
 },
"dealerParameters":[
    {
        "name":"club"
    },
     {
        "name":"token"
    }
    ]
 }
```

**Coded so far:**

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
   "maxResults",
   "counter",
   "customerParameters",
   "dealerParameters"
})
public class CustomerModel {

 @JsonProperty("maxResults")
 private Integer maxResults;
 @JsonProperty("counter")
 private Integer counter;
 @JsonProperty("customerParameters")
 private CustomerParameters customerParameters;
 @JsonProperty("dealerParameters")
 private List<DealerParameter> dealerParameters = null;

 @JsonProperty("customerParameters")
 public CustomerParameters getCustomerParameters() {
  return customerParameters;
  }
 @JsonProperty("customerParameters")
 public void setCustomerParameters(CustomerParameters customerParameters) {
   this.customerParameters = customerParameters;
 }
 @JsonProperty("dealerParameters")
 public List<DealerParameter> getDealerParameters() {
  return dealerParameters;
 }
 @JsonProperty("dealerParameters")
 public void setDealerParameters(List<DealerParameter> dealerParameters) {
  this.dealerParameters = dealerParameters;
 } 
  // Getter/Setter for other params
    }
```

CustomerParameters.java

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
 "filters"
 })
 public class CustomerParameters {
 @JsonProperty("filters")
 private List<Filter> filters = null;
  // Setter and Getter for filters parameter
}
```

DealerParameters.java

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
 "name"
 })
 public class DealerParameter {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public String getName() {
  return name;
  }
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  }
 }
```

Filter.java

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
  "name",
  "operator",
  "value"
 })
 public class Filter {

 @JsonProperty("name")
 private String name;
 @JsonProperty("operator")
 private String operator;
 @JsonProperty("value")
 private List<String> value = null;

 @JsonProperty("value")
 public List<String> getValue() {
 return value;
 }
 @JsonProperty("value")
 public void setValue(List<String> value) {
 this.value = value;
 }
 // Setter and Getter for other properties
}
```

**Missing Part:**

```
   @Controller
   public class TestContoller {
     RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

1. Should I instantiate each pojo class with new operator as below and set all required parameters ? or any other approach of creating JSON payload?

   ```
         CustomerModel customerModel= new CustomerModel();
           customerModel.setMaxResults(1);
         Filter filter= new Filter();
           filter.setName("customerID");
           filter.setOperator("-");
           filter.setValue(Arrays.asList("club"));
         CustomerParameters customerParameters = new CustomerParameters();
           customerParameters.setFilters(Arrays.asList(filter));
         customerModel.setCustomerParameters(customerParameters);
   ```
2. For DealerParameter class, I want to create multiple objects with **same key** different value(see the json payload I mentioned above). Below code creates only one object "name":"dealerId"

   ```
         DealerParameter dealerParameter = new DealerParameter();
          dealerParameter.setName("dealerId");
          customerModel.setDealerParameters(dealerParameter);

          ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customerModel);
     restTemplate.exchange(todo); // restful service call
   ```

   }

Comment: You can use Factory pattern to encapsulate details and thus reduce boilerplate code of instantiating CustomerModel objects

Comment: Did you consider trying @ConfigurationProperties to create your customerModel object? That may not be the best approach, but it may help.

Comment: @Nikolai. Could you please provide some reference?

Comment: @Alex https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

you are already using "**ObjectMapper**", And ObjectMapper has readValue() method. By using readValue() method you can populate all data at a time like below:--

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 //populating data from json string to POJO  
 CustomerModel  customerModel = objectMapper.readValue(<json String>,CustomerModel.class);

 System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customerModel); // print all data
```